# Changes in a Sql Server instance after the restart of the DB engine service

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

What changes usually happens when we restart a SQL Server instance? We know some of them like,

1) tempdb is recreated
2) errorlog recreated

but other than these I think there are much more. Can someone kindly list some of them? Internal level will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Considered reading the log that SQL Server creates on every step it does when starting?

Comment: There is no information about changes made to an instance after restart in the log.

Comment: Except all the operations happening to the databases in the instance. Which are part of the instance. So they are changes to the instance. Which means your statement is false.

Comment: I am not here to argue, but when you know that your are not correct there is nothing in excepting that. Log only shows the info databases its starting after restart.

Comment: And rolling back / validating. There may be changes to the database files during restart. If you cound validating (it is not automatically regenerating) tempdb, why not that?